Formatting JSON with Prettier via ESLint (@eslint/json)
How can I fix JSON formatting issues with Prettier via ESLint.
I'm trying to use @eslint/json, rather than say eslint-plugin-json, it being the official supported plugin, and in an ideal world I'd leverage its recommended config.
One of my attempts is below, but nothing I've tried works.
Running eslint ./tests/bad.json --fix does nothing.
If I introduce lints to the bad.json, like duplicate keys, the ESLint rules will detect them, but I can't get it/Prettier to pick up the formatting problems as errors.
Running Prettier directly works: prettier --write tests/bad.json
Advice appreciated.
// eslint.config.mjs
import eslintJson from '@eslint/json'
import eslintPluginPrettier from 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

const config = [
  {
    files: ["**/*.json"],
    language: "json/json",
    languageOptions: {
      parser: 'json',
    },
    plugins: {
      prettier: eslintPluginPrettier,
      ...eslintJson.configs.recommended.plugins,
    },
    rules: {
      ...eslintJson.configs.recommended.rules,
      'prettier/prettier': ['error', { parser: 'json' }],
    },
  },
]
export default config

// .prettierrc
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}

// package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/json": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint": "^9.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "^16.3.0"
  }
}

// tests/bad.json
{
  "a": 1,"d":8,
"b":  "two",



"c":10}```

